# Symfony & Propel remove join after addJoin?

Tags: symfony1, propel

I have a need to remove a joined table after it has already been added via addJoin() method.  Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Perhaps it might be helpful to explain the context and why you want to do this so that we might be able to give you some help. A code sample is generally a good start.

Comment: Do you mean to remove a join before the select executes? If so, is it possible for the code to be reorganised so that the join is not added in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You could add new methods to handle this case by hand, it's not a feature provided by Propel (actually, it doesn't make sense).

I suggest you store all your join conditions in an array, then you can add/remove them. Before to create the query, just iterate over the array, and add stored conditions.